# Overriding/replacing a jquery click function

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-animate

Forgive me if this is an obvious question.

I'm working on a page with a script I can't remove or alter. A button is clicked, which loads some items onto the page with an ajax request, and then triggers an annoying scrolljacking animation for the page.

**The goal:** I still want the items to load when the button is clicked, but I don't want the scroll animation.

I'm able to add my own custom js to the page (below where the default script is added). How do I interrupt or override the original script to remove the scrolling behaviour?

Here's a simplified example.

```css
.group{
 background: cyan;
 height:400px;
 width:400px;
 margin:10px
}
.load-more{
 background:#88f;
 width:360px;
 text-align:center;
 margin:10px;
 padding:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- markup -->
<div class="groups-listing">
 <div class="group"></div>
</div>
<div class="load-more">Load more</div>

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(".load-more").click(function () {
  //loading another item
  $(".groups-listing").append('<div class="group"></div>');
  
  //annoying animated scrolling
  $("html, body").animate(
   {
    scrollTop: $(".groups-listing .group").last().offset().top
   },2000
  );
 });
</script>
<script>
  // custom js, override must go here.
</script>
```

The actual problem can be found here: https://obsu.unionclouduat.org/groups
I think my simplified example is analagous, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Sledgehammer approach, but might be useful/what you're after: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/

Comment: @freedomn-m that's interesting, but I think this would just immediately take me to the end of the scroll, right? I want the window not to scroll at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to `unbind()` and reasign the event ?

```
// custom js, override must go here.

$(".load-more").unbind().click(function () {
        //loading another item
        $(".groups-listing").append('<div class="group"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @webolive!, this works perfectly for my simple example. The actual use case at https://obsu.unionclouduat.org/groups seems a lot more complex. I'm going to try it out there too before accepting the answer.